# OutOfMemory Error: Synchronized blocks inside static methods

Tags: java, out-of-memory, synchronized

I'm getting an OutOfmemory error while execution of getInstance. I checked the thread dumps and found the thread is BLOCKED (Waiting for Monitor Lock on getInstance).

I'm very novice at multi-threading. Could anyone please explain if below implementation is correct or not? If not, how can it be improved?

```
class MyClass {
    private static MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    public static MyClass getInstance() throws Exception {
        synchronized (instance) {...}
    }
    public static MyClass clearInstance() throws Exception {
        synchronized (instance) {...}
    }
}
```

Comment: How could you reference to a non-static field inside static methods?

Comment: @shizhz.. Sorry I updated the code!

Comment: I think would better if you post the implementation of method `getInstance` and `clearInstance`. And the way to reproduce the problem:-)

Comment: @shizhz..Really sorry! I wish I could post the exact code, but it could be a breach of security at my company. Hope you understand!

Comment: In that case you can't get an answer. There is nothing here that leaks memory. NB You should synchronize on `MyClass.class`, not on `instance`, which might be null. More conveniently, just make the `getInstance()` and `clearInstance()` methods `synchronized`. But unless `clearInstance()` nulls `instance` I don't see any need for synchronization at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem about multi threading but when you create an object of `Myclass` it has an instance variable `instance` which creates another object of `Myclass` and it goes into a never ending loop.

So, that's why you are getting an out of memory or stack overflow error.

Comment: So you mean, I should synchronized on two different instance of MyClass?

Comment: @Sanchit Khera you cannot create an instance of an object which recursively makes instances of itself.

Comment: `instance` is not an instance member, and no stack overflow is mentioned.